# Invoking Worklight Adapter and Displaying that JSON data in list view as strings

Tags: java, javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

This is my adapter.impl.js code.

```
 //This procedure implementation is to get all the details from the table which in database.
 var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from employee");
 function procedure1() {
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
    parameters : []
});
}
```

This is my JSON data retrieved from SQL Adapter in worklight.

```
{
"isSuccessful": true,
"resultSet": [
  {
     "EMAIL": "bkandregula@gmail.com",
     "ID": 1,
     "NAME": "Bhanu Kandregula"
  },
  {
     "EMAIL": "rbkandregula@gmail.com",
     "ID": 2,
     "NAME": "Raghu Kandregula"
  },
  {
     "EMAIL": "shyamsurisetty@gmail.com",
     "ID": 3,
     "NAME": "Shyam Surisetty"
  },
  {
     "EMAIL": "bunny@gmail.com",
     "ID": 4,
     "NAME": "Bunny"
  },
  {
     "EMAIL": "divya@gmail.com",
     "ID": 5,
     "NAME": "Divya Sri"
  },
  {
     "EMAIL": "chandhu@gmail.com",
     "ID": 6,
     "NAME": "Chandana"
  }
]
}
```

Not I was to invoke this adapter from Client side and display this data in list view on my mobile console. For that, this is the code which I used in client side js file.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
LoadSQLRecords();}

function loadSQLRecords(){
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'MySQLadap',
    procedure : 'procedure1',
    parameters : []
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : loadSQLQuerySuccess,
    onFailure : loadSQLQueryFailure
});
}

function loadSQLQuerySuccess(result) {
    WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
    displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
}

function loadSQLQueryFailure(result) {
    WL.Logger.error("Retrieve failure");
}

function displayFeeds(items) {
    var ul = $('#itemsList');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].id);
        li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].name));
        li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].email));
        li.append($('<hr>'));
        ul.append(li);
    }
  }
```

And this my HTML file code to display my data on screen.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="itemsList"></ul>
 </div>
```

But This is not working with me. I have been searching many blogs and sites, But I was unable to trigger this. Please do help me in invoking adapter and display that data in list view on mobile console. Thank you.

Comment: Open Chrome's developer tools and check in its console what error you're getting... make sure to refresh the page when the console is open.

Comment: Done @IdanAdar, But unable to got output. Code seems good, but Don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you see in the console? Which error do you get? what do you see in the screen?

Comment: Add your adapter-impl.js code to the question.

Comment: I did @IdanAdar, pease do have a look at my adapter code. Thank you.

Comment: Sure @IdanAdar, I'm a freshmen to start overflow. I will learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the below and then re-deploy the application.

1. You have misspelled a function name:

   `LoadSQLRecords` should be `loadSQLRecords`.

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       LoadSQLRecords(); // Upper-case 'L'; should be lower-case.
   }

   function loadSQLRecords(){
       var invocationData = {
           adapter : 'MySQLadap',
           procedure : 'procedure1',
           parameters : []
       };
   };
   ```

   You should have seen the following in the Chrome DevTools' console prior to the fix:

   ```
   worklight.js:5147 Uncaught Exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadSQLRecords is not defined at (compiled_code):4
   main.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadSQLRecords is not defined
   ```
2. You need to change the following in order to actually display any values.

   - use `items.invocationResult.resultSet`
   - use correct capitalization for the properties

   From:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].id);
       li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].name));
       li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].email));
       li.append($('<hr>'));
       ul.append(li);
   }
   ```

   To:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < items.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i++) {
       var li = $('<li/>').html(items.invocationResult.resultSet[i].ID);
       li.append($('<li/>').html(items.invocationResult.resultSet[i].NAME));
       li.append($('<li/>').html(items.invocationResult.resultSet[i].EMAIL));
       li.append($('<hr>'));
       ul.append(li);
   }
   ```

Comment: @BhanuPrakash, Good to hear. Please mark as Answered.